# Linear Programming Tool/Libraries for Java

Tags: java, linear-programming

I'd like to set up a large linear programming model to solve an interesting problem.  I would be most comfortable in Java.  What tools/libraries are available?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143020/mathematical-optimization-library-for-java-free-or-open-source-recommendatio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used [lp_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) with success. It looks like there is a native Java API, but I've only used the text file interface. It supports the semi-standard MPS and LP file formats, which I found more convenient for trying out different solvers (such as [glpsol](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/)).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend lp_solve for several reasons. 1) Crashes regularly for large LP problems. 2) Very hard to debug errors/crashes (e.g., xfree memory free error, corrupted double linked list etc. 3) Very bad API (the file interface is decent) but the array based C style API is horrible.

Answer (score 14):

There were several suggestions from an [earlier question that I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143020/mathematical-optimization-library-for-java-free-or-open-source-recommendations):

- [CPLEX](http://www.ilog.com/products/cplex)
- [Dash](http://www.dashoptimization.com/home/cgi-bin/example.pl#bcl_java)
- [OptimJ](http://www.ateji.com/optimj.html)
- [COIN-OR](http://www.coin-or.org/)
- [lp_solve](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve)

and possibly more...

Answer (score 3):

Currently, google digs up this Java Linear Programming libs:

- http://scpsolver.org/
- http://javailp.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.joptimizer.com/linearProgramming.html
- http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2012/11/yet-another-java-linear-programming-library/
- http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/optimization.html
- http://ojalgo.org/

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution. Here, this question is off-topic as it asks for off-site resources. It's very old and the rules were different back then, but today this kind of question is not acceptable on SO.

Comment: @Kyll Thanks for the comment. Was not aware of this guidance yet. FWIW, this question paraphrased what I was looking for, which was how I found it in the first place. Next, I summarized my findings.