# Integer Linear Programming Java: Multiple Open Source and Commercial tools are available. Which one to use?

Tags: java, linear-programming, apache-commons

I need to use Integer Linear Programming API/Tool for my application. Though my application is in Java but I don’t mind calling an EXE (Tool) from Java providing input using file (MPS, etc).

My search analysis is as follows:
There are multiple Open Source and Commercial tools available to solve ILP  Following I found and think are useful for my needs.
 1. Gnu LP Kit(GLPK): I think this is the oldest and probably most stable and efficient
 2. IP_Solve: Has good reviews about it.
 3. JavaILP: Found this, but not much reviews about it
 4. Apache Common-Math: Supports LP but not ILP, so ruled out.
 5. Coin-OR

Can you please suggest which one shall be the best in terms of stability, efficiency, acceptance, etc

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linear Programming Tool/Libraries for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260442/linear-programming-tool-libraries-for-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer.
I am finally using LP Solve. The good things about this is (which may be present in other LP solver tools as well) is the timeout option. Thus I can get the optimal result in the mentioned timeout seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully called another free LP/MIP solver called [LPSolve](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/) from java using their java wrapper. It is a pretty good solver for decent sized problems. I was solving problems with more than 5000 integer variables. From your list, it looks like you want to confine yourself to free tools; otherwise, there are commercial options available.