# Solve Linear integer programming for petri nets in Java

Tags: java, linear-programming, integer-programming

Summary of my issue:
I have system of linear equations out of a petri net like this (ILP):

```
int[][] a = {
        {-1, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, -1, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, -1, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, -1},
        {0, 0, 1, -1},
        {0, 0, 0, 1}};

    int[] A = {0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1};

x1, x2, x3, x4>=0;
x1, x2, x3, x4;  //--> must be integer
```

These problems could have many more variables and constraints.
The equations are never inequations. It also could be maximized or minimized.

I checked a few examples for all integer problems, but they couldn't handle systems with more variables than constrains or the other way around.

In a software like [lp_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) I could handle these problems, but for this solution I have to handle to many .dll files and wrapper stuff.

I'm searching for a solution in Java or an easy embedding library. I would really appreciate your help, since I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260442/linear-programming-tool-libraries-for-java

Answer (score 0):

I have some Java code you could maybe use that is feeding this stuff to an SMT solver.

Basically the Petri net is represented as two sparse matrices see class [hosting the net](https://github.com/lip6/ITSTools/blob/master/fr.lip6.move.gal.structural/src/fr/lip6/move/gal/structural/StructuralReduction.java#L29-L35)

A usage example feeding this to an SMT solver as constraints can be found here : [code feeding a state equation](https://github.com/lip6/ITSTools/blob/28fa1c65196b1ba75516ae6af2bc8210671ca079/smt/fr.lip6.move.gal.gal2smt/src/fr/lip6/move/gal/gal2smt/DeadlockTester.java#L235-L278)

Wrapping an SMT solver has proven more versatile and comfortable than having plugged an ILP solver in my experience.