# install glpk error while Building a wheel for glpk (PEP 517) ... none of ways worked

Tags: pulp, python-wheel, glpk

im going to solve Linear Programming Problem and so i need "pulp" library, but while executing a simple code;

```
# solve the problem
status = myLpProblem.solve(GLPK(msg=1))
```

THIS ERROR HAPPENS:
*PuLP: cannot execute glpsol.exe*

so i try to install "glpk" but i faced with this error:

```
 Building wheel for glpk (PEP 517) ... error   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command: 'c:\users\karmian\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\karmian\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Karmian\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp994fjkt2'
       cwd: C:\Users\Karmian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q1cmpyrg\glpk   Complete output (5 lines):   running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_ext   building 'glpk' extension   error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/  
----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for glpk Failed to build glpk ERROR: Could not build wheels for glpk which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

**I try different way people suggest, like**

-upgrade,downgrade pip,wheel ,python

- install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 from that link and launch "windows
  poweshell" so try installing by it
- pip install glpk --no-binary
- install "glpk" from local file(which i download from:
  https://pypi.org/project/glpk/#files

**and none of them worked!**
of course i doubted about whether i installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 truely or not, cause after download installer, i didn't change default setting(i dont know what i should change)and directly press install ,(settings on workload tab,installation locations and..)
i had also some constraints .( for example if i choose "C++ build tools" in first tab it needs 6 gig capacity to install,which i had not.
[picture of installer setting is available here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmRF0.png)
should i change setting?

please help me to find a solution or better "optimization library" instead of "pulp"

im using :

1. virtual env python environment
2. visual studio as my editor of python
3. last version of python:3.8.1(i try some older versions too)
4. pip version 20.2.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing GLPK (GNU Linear Programming Kit) on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513666/installing-glpk-gnu-linear-programming-kit-on-windows)

Comment: thank you for this suggestion, i want to check whether i can do it in python ,itself without any other external solver. or other software as R etc. so yet im going to check other python libraries or find a way to solve installing GLPK package. i try install package as the last answer in link mentions,but it faced same error again.

Comment: GPLK is a solver that does not come with pulp. You can try the CBC solver that comes bundled in pulp. You just need to change your line to `status = myLpProblem.solve()
` or to `status = myLpProblem.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=1))` and that should solve the issue, and the problem itself.

Answer (score 3):

after many days of troubleshooting I found a way that may work for you too. I know that you're on windows, if you adjust it on your os this might help

***This worked on mint and on my Mac.***

Firstly you have to download the latest version of glpk from their website, http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glpk/

After downloading put it in a folder(do not uncompress it yet) cd into that folder and run this command ***$ tar -xzf glpk5.0.tar.gz***

Then you have to configure it, as of my knowledge the problem on Mac was an issue of permissions.
***$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local***

Now you have to compile it by running ***make***

Lastly ***$ sudo make install***

It should take some time in the last 2 steps.

If everything went fine you can check with these two commands

***$ which glpsol***

***$ glpsol --help***

Last but not least you run ***$ pip3 install glpk***

This is the way that worked for me, I hope it will help someone else too. :)

Comment: I would say this answer is helpful. I've sorted out my case.