# apt-get is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use pyomo in jupyter notebook and I have encountered the following problem:
`apt-get is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I am using the following lines in jupyter notebook:

```
!pip install -q pyomo
!apt-get install -y -qq glpk-utils
```

Apparently, `!pip` does not give me any error while `!apt-get` does. I am using using Windows 10 and I have also tried `conda install posix` and using `%%bash`:

```
%%bash
pip install -q pyomo
apt-get install -y -qq glpk-utils
```

which gives the following error: `bash: line 2: apt-get: command not found`

Answer (score 1):

apt-get is a linux command and won't work on windows. You will have to look for alternate ways of installing this package (glpk-utils) on you machine. Links for reference:

[Installing GLPK (GNU Linear Programming Kit) on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513666/installing-glpk-gnu-linear-programming-kit-on-windows)

https://winglpk.sourceforge.net/