# ILP solvers with small memory footprint

Tags: boolean, nlp, out-of-memory, linear-programming

I'm trying to solve a sequence-labelling problem by formulating it as an integer linear program (as an experiment to see how well doing it in that way works). I've already found [some suggestions for solvers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/502102/1391325) but I would like to get some more fine-grained advice due to some constraints I'm under (yes, that pun was actually intended).

I'm running out of memory on more than half of my sequences due to their length while using [COIN-OR](http://www.coin-or.org/) although I see no reason I need to use so much memory for my problem at hand: This is a Boolean linear program, so I would theoretically need only one bit per feature. However, e.g. [the COIN Open Solver Interface](https://projects.coin-or.org/Osi/) seems to be able to use only double values for e.g. defining constraints.

Are there any (free) ILP packages which are well-suited for either Boolean problems or at least for problems with a very small range of potential values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPLEX seems to be considered approximately the state of the art, and in my experience for hard ILPs it is often better than any free solver I found.  Unfortunately, CPLEX is not free, except for academic users; IBM does offer free access to CPLEX for students and researchers at educational institutions, if you fit that description.