# Simplex solver Library Help

Tags: java, optimization, linear-programming

I have to migrate  some old code which used the c  based LPPSolver library to solve a Simplex problem. My problem in Java is to find anon commercial JAVA based solver which can handle large number of variables. I  have tried the Apache SimplexSolver. But in most of my cases I get not feasible solution. 
Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531049/java-library-simplex-linear-programming-optimization http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143020/mathematical-optimization-library-for-java-free-or-open-source-recommendation

Comment: Yes I have read these posts. But they never really really gave a solution. One of them proposed the Apache SimplexSolver which I tried out but I am not getting reliable solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

- [LPSOLVE](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/)

Comment: Thanks. But basically I want a performent Java based Solver. LPSOLVE has  a JAVA interface but the core solver is in C

Comment: I have serious doubts about finding a good Java-based solver.

Answer (score 0):

¿Have you looked at eh [COIN-OR](http://www.coin-or.org/projects/) projects? Maybe there is a Java-based solver.

But the matter seems to be that your problem has no solution with your parameters and data. You can try to solve it on any of the solvers of the [NEOS Server](http://www.neos-server.org/neos/) to see where the problem could be.