# Pure Java open-source libraries for portfolio selection (= constrained, non-linear optimization)?

Tags: java, open-source, nonlinear-optimization

Does anyone know or has experience with a pure Java library to [select portfolios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_portfolio_theory#Mathematically) or do some similar kinds of [quadratic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Software_packages_that_include_QP_solvers) with constraints?

There seems to be a lot of tools, as already [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502102/best-open-source-mixed-integer-optimization-solver) [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143020/mathematical-optimization-library-for-java-free-or-open-source-recommendation) - but what I would like to use is a pure Java implementation. Since I want to call the library from within another open-source software with a BSD-ish license I would prefer LGPL over GPL.

Any help is appreciated. If you don't know such libraries, which is the most simple algorithm you would suggest to implement? It has to cope with an inequality constraint (all `x_i` >= 0) and an equality constraint (sum of all `x_i` = 1).

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, but I do like the way you've phrased it. +1

Comment: See [this video of Investment Portfolio optimization with OptaPlanner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdyIf0JG94Y) (open source, ASL, java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [ojAlgo](http://ojalgo.org). This is FOSS with a business friendly licence.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look...

Answer (score 2):

I think [WebCab Portfolio](http://www.webcabcomponents.com/Java/api/portfolio/index.shtml) may help you. It will handle Markowitz models, efficient frontiers etc. Is that the sort of thing you're addressing above ?

Unfortunately the licensing may cause you problems (but it's runtime-royalty-free, which *may* be of use)

Comment: Yes, I basically want to calculate an efficient frontier.
Thank you for the suggestion, I did not know about this tool. Anyhow, the $677 license fee for my team is quite some money... and the tool has many features I will never need (e.g. their scenario approach or support for the CAPM)... :-/

Comment: @RolandEwald This is no more a comercial product i believe.

Comment: @VibeeshanRC yes you are right, it says so on the product page (https://www.componentsource.com/product/webcab-portfolio-j2ee/licensing)