# Java Linear Algebra / Convex Optimization Libraries

Tags: java, linear-algebra

I don't know what is proper etiquette -- if I should split this into two questions (one about Linear Algebra, one about Convex Optimization), please let me know.

I'm interested in:
(1) what library should I use for Linear Algebra in Java?
(2) what library should I use for convex optimization in Java?
(3) what benchmarks do we have for java libraries vs C libraries

Please note, although Java specifies platform independent floating point representation (which I believe makes things much slower) -- I'm willing to sacrifice that. It's okay for me if, on different platforms, my Java floating point ends up getting different values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convex Optimization , there is already one link here:

[mathematical optimization library for Java --- free or open source recommendations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143020/mathematical-optimization-library-for-java-free-or-open-source-recommendatio)

For Liner ALgebra, you can use Colt

http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [JOptimizer](http://www.joptimizer.com) , open source java convex optimization project