# Fast (possibly approximate) linear programming library

Tags: shared-libraries, linear-programming, glpk

I need to solve a sparse linear programming problem, and I am looking for a library for the same.

**Primary requirements:**
The most important requirement is that it should be very fast. A randomised approximate solution is acceptable, if it is faster.

**LP specifications:**
The size of the problem is a function of 2 parameters : P and Q, with P << Q most of the times.
No. of variables ~ P + Q
No. of constraints ~ 2Q
The constraint matrix is sparse - it has only O(Q) non-zero entries.

**Solutions tried**
1) MATLAB : The *linprog* function of MATLAB is not particularly useful in our setting, as it takes very long to solve the LP.
2) GLPK : *glpk_simplex* is also not as fast as expected - for a problem with P=15, Q=15,000, I need to get an answer in at most 10 seconds, but *glpk_simplex* takes 20-25 minutes. *glpk_interior* runs out of memory for a problem of the above-mentioned size.

Can anyone suggest some efficient libraries? Please suggest both free and commercially available ones, that can be used to solve the problem exactly or approximately.

Comment: Heh... "A randomized approximate solution is acceptable, if it is faster." Ok, 42 is the solution... Roughly random, and very approximate, given some arbitrary threshhold...

Comment: [lpsolve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) is a very efficient (single threaded) open-source LP/MILP solver. On my 3 year old i7 laptop, it has solved *dense* problems with 1000 variables and 2000 constraints in less than 5 seconds. As far as commercial solvers go, I recommend you look at [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/), which provides an efficient multi-threaded LP engine.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding other solver options, here are two SO questions that you should take a look at if you haven't checked them out already:

1. [SO Question on which solvers to
   use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502102/best-open-source-mixed-integer-optimization-solver?rq=1)
2. [Java Solver
   Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143020/mathematical-optimization-library-for-java-free-or-open-source-recommendatio)

But the reason I am posting is that I have a couple of other suggestions for you, rather than going for the solver speed. (Something might work for Q ~ 15K in your problem, but if Q gets bigger, you will have to search for even faster solvers.)

#### Other suggestions to try

1. Have you played around with the solver `options` in either MATLAB or GLPK? There are quite a number of things you could try: Setting `iteration limit`, or `Timelimit` (to 10000 milliseconds).
2. Look into **decomposing and relaxing your formulation**. Typically, in these large LP's there is a nice underlying structure, but a few dense constraints play spoil-sport and those are the ones that give the solver trouble. If you can identify those, you can relax those, and maybe even throw it into the objective function with a multiplier.

   To make it a little more concrete, you consider **Lagranian relaxations** for 'troublesome constraints.' (As one reference to what I'm referring to [see how problem 12.3 becomes 12.4 here](http://www.ens-lyon.fr/DI/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/LagrangianRelax.pdf)
   after being relaxed. You can do the same for dense several constraints in your problem.

Hope this helps you move forward.